# FancyBox iframe isn't loading PHP page

Tags: jquery, iframe

I've looked at a few post here but I can't seem to find the resolution to my issue. I'm trying to get FancyBox to load a php page of mine. I have an html page loading perfectly fine but this PHP page doesn't load. Please help...

This is the jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--var $= jQuery.noConflict();-->
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and 
        overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if 
        clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change 
        title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + 
             this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, 
            arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, 
            enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : '/wp-content/themes/listings/login.php',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script>
```

This is where I try to open the iframe

```
<div class="button-link" style="float:left"> <a href="<?php echo 
get_template_directory();?>/login.php" class="fancybox 
fancybox.iframe">Sign In &raquo;</a></div><div class="button-link" 
style="float:left; margin-right:15px"><a href="#"> &laquo; Sign Up </a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: If this is exactly the code that you run - you have javascript errors, which cause the script to stop running. Check the errors on the console of the developer tools (F12 in most browsers).

Comment: ok well I see this error 
(index):629Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
i added the fancybox plugin and it got rid of this error now its back. How do i fix this???

Comment: Did you remember to include the source of fancybox?

Comment: Well i had them included in the header formerly but they weren't showing up on the page. So I installed the plugin. All the galleries do the iframe stuff when i did that so i figured it would be fine.

Comment: the crazy thing is the html page would load now nothing is loading.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand if the problem was fixed or not.

Comment: it's ok...I see what I did...I actually had all the include files in the header and thought the plugin rectified this problem so I deleted the files but it didn't. I just added them and now it's working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add back the jquery include files I took off.